# Problem with enabling FooTable module

Tags: javascript

I've installed the [FooTable](https://www.drupal.org/project/footable) module but I can't enable it. The error message when I try to enable it is this:
"The FooTable jQuery plugin is missing. See README.md for instructions on how to download and extract it. (Currently using FooTable Not found)"

But I've already installed and enabled the jquery plugin but the error message appeared again.

I followed the README.md instructions about the directory where I have to place the zip file downloaded on https://github.com/bradvin/FooTable but the error message appeared again.

What else can I do?

What are the other modules similar to FooTable?

[image: Footable Error]

Comment: _the directory where I have to place the zip file_ ... you did unzip it, right? :) As long as sites/all/libraries/FooTable/js/footable.js exists (alongside the rest of the library files) you shouldn't have a problem

Comment: Yes of course...the directory is a bit different than what you and the instructions say but all the reminder modules run...this is my directory: D:\directory drupal\BookLibrary\sites\all\modules\libraries\FooTable\js

Comment: That is the same directory @Clive said, except that he did show the path relative to the directory where Drupal is installed.

Comment: Did you delete any files from that directory? The Libraries API module checks the content of some files to verify which version of the library you installed; if it doesn't find that file, it will say the library is not installed.

Comment: No, I didn't change the files in that directory.